# Minimum steps on a numberline

Tags: mathematics, optimization, number-theory

Given an infinite numberline, you start at zero. On every i'th move you can either move i places to the right, or i places to the left. How, in general, would you calculate the minimum number of moves to get to a target point x? For example:

if x = 9:

move 1: starting at zero, move to 1

move 2: starting at 1, move to 3

move 3: starting at 3, move to 0

move 4: starting at 0, move to 4

move 5: starting at 4, move to 5

Comment: This seems like another mathbook-type problem to me.

Comment: Your example is not a minimum: 9=1+2-3+4+5, can be done in 5 steps

Comment: @Mithrandir I think so. VTC.

Comment: I say "don't close" -- unless it is mandatory to have a real-life story enclosing the real puzzle to be solved.

Comment: I want to go to school with these VTCers; clearly their textbooks have much more interesting problems than mine.

Comment: Shouldn't the last line end with "move to 9"?

Comment: @Rosie F  Exactly. I'm fairly sure that if it had been "bob and alice playing a game ... using counters on a board ... etc ", then there would be no votes to close, despite the problem being identical. That being said, I can understand if people think this belongs on the math exchange

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First,

> you need to find $n$, for which $S_n=1+2+\dots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}2\ge x$

Then,

> find a subset of the numbers in range $[1, n]$ which sum to $\frac{S_n-x}2$. This can always be done if the parity of $S_n$ is the same as the parity for $x$. This means, that if $m$ is the lowest number for which $S_m\ge x$, then at least one of $S_m$, $S_{m+1}$ or $S_{m+2}$ will do the work.

With the help of this

> adding the rest, and subtracting the above will give you the desired solution

Answer (score 5):

First you calculate the smallest $n$ with $\frac{1}{2}n(n+1) \geq x$

if $\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)-x$ is odd then increase $n$ by $1$ if $n$ is even or increase $n$ by $2$ if $n$ is odd.

Now $\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)-x$ is even

Now you can put a minus sign before some numbers that have the sum $\frac{1}{2} (\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)-x)$ and you are done.

### Example:

$x=23$

The smallest $n$ with $\frac{1}{2}n(n+1) \geq x$ is $n=7$

$\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)-x = 28-23 = 5$ is odd and $n$ is also odd so we have to increase $n$ by $2$.

That means $n=9$

$\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)-x) = \frac{1}{2}(45-23) = 11$

So we have to put a minus in front of numbers with the sum $11$. For example $2$ and $9$.

Result: 1-2+3+4+5+6+7+8-9

Answer (score 3):

It comes out to be a better puzzle than it was voted to close for!

> One thing is for sure, if the given number $x$ is [a triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), the answer is its position in the sequence  [1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, 66](https://oeis.org/A000217)
>  which is given by
>
>  $$\left\lfloor\dfrac{\sqrt{1+8x}-1}{2}\right\rfloor$$

Also:

> [here is my code](http://ideone.com/Gvw9Ee), which gives a very interesting pattern,
>
>  output: 
>  
>  `For x=1, ans : 1
>  For x=2, ans : 3
>  For x=3, ans : 2
>  For x=4, ans : 3
>  For x=5, ans : 5
>  For x=6, ans : 3
>  For x=7, ans : 5
>  For x=8, ans : 4
>  For x=9, ans : 5
>  For x=10, ans : 4
>  For x=11, ans : 5
>  For x=12, ans : 7
>  For x=13, ans : 5
>  For x=14, ans : 7
>  For x=15, ans : 5
>  For x=16, ans : 7
>  For x=17, ans : 6
>  For x=18, ans : 7
>  For x=19, ans : 6
>  For x=20, ans : 7
>  For x=21, ans : 6
>  For x=22, ans : 7
>  For x=23, ans : 9
>  For x=24, ans : 7
>  For x=25, ans : 9
>  For x=26, ans : 7`
>
>
>  which is :
>  $1,3,2,3,5,3,5,4,5,4,5,7,5,7,5,7,6,7,6,7,6,7,9,7,9,7,9$,... [OEIS/A140358](http://oeis.org/A140358)
>  check the values [up to $1000$ here](http://oeis.org/A140358/b140358.txt).
>  see [this final code](http://ideone.com/LrNioV)

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int i,n,t;
int main()
{   int x,ans;

for(cin>>t;t;t--)
{   cin>>x;
    n=floor((sqrt(1+8*x)-1)/2);
    //cout<<n<<endl;
    i=(n*(n+1))/2;
    //cout<<x<<", sum:"<<i<<", N:"<<n<<endl;
    if(n%2) //n is odd
    {
        if((x-i)%2) ans=n+2;
        else ans=n+1;
    }
    else
    {
        if((x-i)%2) ans=n+1;
        else ans=n+3;
    }
    cout<<">! For x="<<x<<", ans : "<<ans<<endl;
    }
}
```